# SQL Server : convert nvarchar type to INT

Tags: sql-server

I need to convert a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column which has values as shown below to `INTEGER`.

I'm trying this code which isn't working:

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, CriteriaValue) 
FROM OUTPUT_KEY
```

Table has these values:

```
£19,000,000
£10,000,000
£10,000,000
```

I get this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '£10,000,000' to data type int.

The following also doesn't work

```
DECLARE @ConvertValue AS NVARCHAR(50)
SET @ConvertValue = '19,000,000'

SELECT CONVERT(INT, @ConvertValue)
```

Error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '19,000,000' to data type int.

Comment: Maybe you should remove the pound sign....

Comment: The pound symbol and commas are not part of an INT. Why are you storing them in the first place? You should be doing that formatting in your front-end application instead of in the database (in other words, the exact opposite of what you're doing now).

Comment: updated question...

Comment: Why are you using a `nvarchar(MAX)` too? I doubt you're going to need to store a number that contains 1000000000 characters. That would be an insane amount of money (probably more than the entire world worth in JPY)

Comment: we are using nvarchar(max) as we do store long strings also in same column... along with numbers

Comment: That's a very important piece of information you failed to tell us there... Why are you mixing data in one column? That smells like a poor database design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you are trying to convert to an integer contains a comma and pound symbol.  SQL Server is unable to handle the implicit conversion for you because of that.

You can read all about that here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

In this specific example you'll need to remove those characters prior to the conversion.  Here's an example using a nested REPLACE if all you have is the pound and comma:

```
DECLARE @ConvertValue AS NVARCHAR(50);
SET @ConvertValue = '£19,000,000';
SET @ConvertValue = REPLACE(REPLACE(@ConvertValue, ',', ''), '£', '');

SELECT @ConvertValue;
```

If your resulting data type was money, SQL would implicitly handle the conversion for you:

```
DECLARE @ConvertValue AS NVARCHAR(50);
SET @ConvertValue = '£19,000,000';
SELECT CONVERT(MONEY, @ConvertValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on sample data & query, you need `REPLACE()` to make it work :

```
DECLARE @ConvertValue nvarchar(50)
SET @ConvertValue = '19,000,000'

SELECT CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(@ConvertValue, ',', ''))
```

If the `@ConvertValue` has `£` also , then you need one more `REPLACE()` :

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(REPLACE(@ConvertValue, '£', ''), ',', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Money Data Type would work better for you

```
Declare @ConvertValue as nvarchar(50)
SET @ConvertValue = '$19,000,000'
SELECT convert (money, @ConvertValue)
```